# Join two queries in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have a Person model which has a birthday.  I would like to create a query that returns all the persons information along with an additional field that tells how many people are sharing each person's birthday.  In SQL I would write it like this:

`SELECT p.name, b.count FROM 
persons as p INNER JOIN
(SELECT birthday as date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM persons GROUP_BY birthday) AS b
WHERE p.birthday = b.date`

With Django querysets I can do the inner select but I don't know how to do the inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems tough to do with the ORM (though maybe possible with [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra)).

You could create a dict of counts by date (max 366 values, if ignoring year):

```
 from django.db.models import Count
 birthdate = lambda d: d.strftime("%m-%d")

 # this runs the subquery in your SQL:
 birthdays = Person.objects.values('birthday')
 counts = birthdays.annotate(count=Count('birthday'))

 counts_by_date = {
     birthdate(r['birthday']): r['count'] 
     for r in counts
 }

 for person in Person.objects.all():
     count = counts_by_date[birthdate(person.birthday)]
     print "%d people share your birthday!" % count
```

Answer (score -1):

I would add a model method to get the count. You can do it using the ORM like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    birthdate = models.DateField()

    def shared_count(self):
        return Person.objects.filter(birthdate=self.birthdate).exclude(pk=self.id).count()
```

Then you can just access the count on the Person instance like this:

```
my_person = Person.objects.get(pk=12)
count = my_person.shared_count()
```

Or access it in a template like this:

```
{{ my_person.shared_count }}
```