# Django JOIN: raw sql vs. in memory

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have an SQL JOIN that does not translate well into the Django ORM syntax and I am wondering which alternative solution is better:

1. Use a raw sql query, or
2. Use two querysets and perform the join in memory to annotate one of them.

I can join the two querysets in linear time, so I don't think 2. would be significantly slower.  But which one of the approaches is better conceptually?

Comment: 2. sounds a lot like [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The problem is that the JOIN is not done on a foreign key.  The field is a date, and I want to return how many other records have that date.  This is the related question I posted before  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798858/join-two-queries-in-django-orm

Comment: The specific example helps. See my answer on your linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary considerations are performance, readability/clarity of the code, and maintainability.

If performance is not an issue here as you say, then clarity and maintainability are the primary factors. Pure Python/Django code is typically clearer to read and follow its purpose than inlining SQL queries as strings in Python code. In my experience, SQL queries as strings are also harder to maintain, as they will not throw syntax errors if your model changes and the query is no longer valid. The issue will be found at runtime instead.

Ultimately the readability and maintainability issues mainly rely on you and any other maintainers, since it will need to be clear and maintainable to you. In my opinion, the SQL string approach is less clear and more brittle.